# How can I handle SQLNonTransientConnectionException and other DAO exception in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring data jpa in my project. I want to handle some exception like SQLNonTransientConnectionException and bubble it up for showing appropriate message. In below stack trace there wasn't any class point to my code.

```
15-Jul-2017 23:12:00.900 WARNING [Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@411e79f0] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1851de77 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
 java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1677)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor88.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQLNonTransientConnectionException` it's sub type of `SQLException` and it's checked excecption.
If you know place where it might come you can add try catch block.
If you want to catch any sqlException you can use AOP (AfterThrowing if you need just to log it and Around if you need wrap exception and re-throw)

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionAdvice {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))",throwing = "e")
    public void catchIfSqlException(JoinPoint joinPoint, SQLException e) {    
        if(e instanceOf SQLNonTransientConnectionException){
           ....
        }
        if(e instanceof ){
           .....
        }
    }

    @Around(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void executeAndWrapSqlExceptionIfOccure(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) 
                                                            throws Throwable {
       try {
          pjp.proceed();
       } catch (Throwable exception) {
            if(e instanceOf SQLNonTransientConnectionException){
                .... wrap and re-throw
           }
           if(e instanceof ){
               .....
           }
       }
    }
}
```